# Is it possible to populate information in unix attributes of active directory using ldap-queries?

Tags: active-directory, openldap, ldap-query

I have 2 machine one is ubuntu machine serve as ldap proxy & other win 2k8 r2 as active directory.

In this scenario , I am successfully able to do ldapsearch to list active directory users , also I am able to modify some attributes of active directory like sn , givename etc (**not unix attributes**) using ldapmodify.

For eg.

```
    ldapmodify -x -H ldap:///  -D "cn=administrator,cn=users,dc=somedomain,dc=com"  -w  somepwd <<EOF
dn: cn=test ad5,cn=Users,dc=somedomain,dc=com
changetype: modify
replace: sn
sn: ad52
EOF
```

**o/p** `modifying entry "cn=test ad5,cn=Users,dc=somedomain,dc=com"`

```
ldapsearch -x -H ldap:///  -D "cn=administrator,cn=users,dc=somedomain,dc=com"  -b "dc=somedomain,dc=com"  -w  somepwd  -LLL  "cn=test ad5"
```

**o/p**

```
dn: cn=test ad5,cn=Users,dc=somedomain,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: USER
cn: test ad5
sn: ad52
givenName: test
distinguishedName: cn=test ad5,cn=Users,dc=somedomain,dc=com
INSTANCETYPE: 4
WHENCREATED: 20170320043245.0Z
WHENCHANGED: 20170320093950.0Z
displayName: test ad5
USNCREATED: 53266
USNCHANGED: 53297
**name: test ad523**
OBJECTGUID:: le66Ipk9yUy0WCRbtKe84w==
USERACCOUNTCONTROL: 66048
BADPWDCOUNT: 0
CODEPAGE: 0
COUNTRYCODE: 0
BADPASSWORDTIME: 0
LASTLOGOFF: 0
LASTLOGON: 0
PWDLASTSET: 131344579654629136
PRIMARYGROUPID: 513
OBJECTSID:: AQUAAAAAAAUVAAAACIWeuT2Mclq4HJrDWAQAAA==
ACCOUNTEXPIRES: 9223372036854775807
LOGONCOUNT: 0
uid: test_ad5
SAMACCOUNTTYPE: 805306368
USERPRINCIPALNAME: test_ad5@somedomain.com
OBJECTCATEGORY: CN=Person,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=somedomain,DC=com
DSCOREPROPAGATIONDATA: 16010101000000.0Z
```

Currently it is possible using GUI i.e populating information manually in [GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QS0yp.png) by selecting nis domain.

Question, is it possible to add/modify to unix attribute like "MSSFU30NISDOMAIN" "uidNumber" "gidNumber" through ldapadd/modify only i.e without GUI?

Here is LDIF file that i have tried with following command

```
ldapmodify -x -H ldap:///  -D "cn=administrator,cn=users,dc=enjaynewldap,dc=com"  -w  Admin@1234 -f l_mod.ldif

dn: cn=test ad5,cn=Users,dc=enjaynewldap,dc=com
changetype: modify
add: homeDirectory
homeDirectory: /home/test_ad5

dn: cn=test ad5,cn=Users,dc=enjaynewldap,dc=com
changetype: modify
add: loginShell
loginShell: /bin/bash

dn: cn=test ad5,cn=Users,dc=enjaynewldap,dc=com
changetype: modify
add: gidNumber
gidNumber: 666

dn: cn=test ad5,cn=Users,dc=enjaynewldap,dc=com
changetype: modify
add: uidNumber
uidNumber: 20005

dn: cn=test ad5,cn=Users,dc=enjaynewldap,dc=com
changetype: modify
add: msSFU30NisDomain
msSFU30NisDomain: enjaynewldap
```

**O/P**

```
modifying entry "cn=test ad5,cn=Users,dc=enjaynewldap,dc=com"
ldap_modify: Undefined attribute type (17)
    additional info: msSFU30NisDomain: attribute type undefined
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can not see why not. You should be able to do this using ldapmodify or any other method using LDIF.

[msSFU30NisDomain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc220535.aspx) is a syntax of String(Printable), String(IA5)
uidNumber is an integer
gidNumber is an integer

Are you having some issue?

Comment: i tried using LDIF but no success. Got 
ldap_modify: Undefined attribute type (17)
 additional info: MSSFU30NISDOMAIN: attribute type undefined

Comment: Also i tried uidNumber & gidNumber, both were successfully added & showed in ldapsearch from my ldap proxy server for that particular record , but when i cross check for same record in unix attribute tab in active directory, it's not reflected. Can you provide example of LDIF for  MSSFU30NISDOMAIN?

Comment: Can we go the other way? Set a value in the GUI and then export the user to LDIF with MSSFU30NISDOMAIN. Acording to https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms678148.aspx, it is an attribute of the user. Please show any LDIFs used and outcomes.

Comment: i have edited question , added content of ldif file that i tried. Also we cant go this way i.e using GUI & exporting. All need is using ldap-queries to active directories.

Comment: Do this JUST for testing. Can we go the other way? Set a value in the GUI and then export the user to LDIF with MSSFU30NISDOMAIN.

Comment: Ok will give a try & let know.

Comment: Hi @ jwilleke , as you told i have set the of unix tab attributes values in GUI and than export content of user to LDIF using LDIFDE command. After exporting Content of unix attribute in file for that user(test ad5) shows me **msSFU30NisDomain: enjaynewldap, uidNumber: 20005(auto inc from previous users), gidNumber: 666, unixHomeDirectory: /home/test_ad5/, loginShell: /bin/bash**

Comment: Can you tell what would be next step ? after exporting user in LDIF

Comment: I am at a loss. I was able to add a user with the msSFU30NisDomain and do a replace on the msSFU30NisDomain without an issue. (AD 2012 R2) Microsoft Active Directory is a little weird from an LDAP perspective and there could be an issue with permissions or the order of adding attributes due to how Dynamic Classes are implemented.

Comment: I am using windows 2008 R2 and facing problem to add msSFU30NisDomain . Should I try in 2012 R2 ?